# Knp paginator get all rows total

Tags: symfony, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

As I noticed in SQL query logger Knp paginator at first counts all records available and then in second query retrieves records that are needed in requested page. I wonder if there is some way to update first query to retrieve additional counts/sums as I would like to get total count/sum in all records available?

Comment: `{{ pagination.getTotalItemCount }}`

Comment: Looks like I'm not expressed clearly what I need. I know how to get total items count. What I need is, for example, the sum of field "price" in all records available.

Comment: The fetch query is not executed until you try to access the results. You need to either execute another query to get the sum or calculate it while looping through it the first time (e.g print it out in tempalte)

Comment: Why not create a query for all the prices and then sum them up and send to the template as a variable to use in Twig template.

Comment: Not a big problem to create one more query but it would be more effective to modify the first one which is executed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ pagination.getTotalItemCount }}
```

use getTotalItemCount method to access the total count